# #1033 - incorrect information in file '. phpmyadmin pma_tracking.frm'

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

i have problem with my xampp, my case is like this
in the beginning i have two xampp on my pc and it worked well, **xampp 3.1.0** on `c:/xampp` and **xampp 3.2.2** on `d:/program/xampp`, but a time i move my xampp 3.1.0 to other drive my MySql cant run, so i change all command at lead to `c:\xampp with d:\program\xampp` on **my.ini** in `d:\program\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`
after that its work, but if i want access my database i found these message

> **#1033 - incorrect information in file '. phpmyadmin pma_tracking.frm'**

thank you all, your solution very help me :)

Comment: probably easiest to just reinstall

Comment: but if i reinstall, my database will be lost

Comment: phpmyadmin, is not your database, its just a script to manage them. deleting it will not touch the database